# How to apply CSS to page wrapper when div is targeted

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, target

I'm building a lightbox that pops up a div called `#lightbox` when the `<a href="#lightbox">`is clicked and the `:target` property is used. So when you click that link the CSS to make the box visible would be `#lightbox:target {display: block}`. I am looking to apply CSS properties to the `#page_wrap` id when the lightbox is the `:target` but I think I'm missing something because my solution isn't working.

I want to apply the following CSS to the `#page_wrap` when `#lightbox:target`:

`overflow: hidden`

The current CSS I have isn't working.

`#lightbox:target + #page_wrap {overflow: hidden}`

Here's my [**codepen.**](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/CpkGj)

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery code should work for you:

```
$("#lightbox").click( function(){ $("#page_wrap").css("overflow","hidden"); } );
```

Place this in your header:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$("#lightbox").click( function(){ $("#page_wrap").css("overflow","hidden"); } );

});
</script>
```

If you are not calling jQuery would would also need:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the header above the above script.

Comment: Is javascript the only solution here? What about a pure CSS solution?

Comment: not sure about pure css... jquery is so prevalent in today's programming that I find it easier because it opens so many doors

Comment: @MattBeckman I was about to post an answer but was beat to it. Javascript is really the only way to do this. CSS3 selectors aren't robust enough to target any element when it's not the one with the pseudo class (like :hover or :target). If the element you wanted to select was somehow  related to #lightbox (such as a direct child #lightbox:target > .child) then you could do pure CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/797343/756329 No way for CSS selectors to ascend. Darn.

Comment: @jmh010 This code doesn't work. In order to get the `overflow:hidden` to apply to the `#page_wrap` you have to open the lightbox then click the div. I need code that will apply the CSS on a click of the `<a href="#lightbox">`, not when the actual div itself is clicked.